# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program Run powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, console-application

I get this error when execute the code. my `powershell` version is `5.1`

here my codes. thanks for any help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var script = @" 
        $ous = 'OU=test,DC=test,DC=local' $When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-20)).Date $ous | ForEach { Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated,* -SearchBase $_ }";
    var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
    powerShell.AddScript(script);
    foreach (var Office in powerShell.Invoke())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Office);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you targeting a lower version of .NET Framework?

Comment: no, i use newer version of .NET Framework

Comment: Which version of Framework are you targeting? Which “System.Management.Automation.dll” are you referencing (what is its path)? Is your program 64 bit or 32 bit? And, though not quite relevant, what is the OS version?

Comment: i solved this problem. i use wrong refference in vs. thans for help !

Comment: You can post your answer and accept it, will be helpful to others.;)